# Is there an R function to solve "find two numbers whose sum is x and product is a maximum" like problems?

Tags: r, optimization

I would like to know if there is library like lpSolve for solving that kind of problems, I do not know if this library allows to include in the constraints the product of the two variables or how I can specify "the product is a maximum".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining a projection onto the feasible region allows us to use unconstrained optimization to optimize this:

```
tot <- 10
proj <- function(x) tot * x / sum(x)
res <- optim(1:2, function(x) -prod(proj(x)))

res$convergence
## [1] 0

-res$value
## [1] 25

proj(res$par)
## [1] 4.999799 5.000201
```

Comment: This is definitely what I was looking for. I do not completely understand what a projection is because I am starting to learn about optimization, but thank you so much :D

Comment: The function *proj* only needs to be *onto*, i.e. for each point y in the feasible region there must be an x such that proj(x) = y.  In this case it is a *projection*, i.e. proj(proj(x)) = proj(x) but that is not necessary, *onto* is enough.